# How do you change the colors of the output when running bin/dev with foreman via a Procfile in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, foreman, procfile

I'm running Rails 7 via foreman with a Procfile with the `bin/dev` command.

The Procfile looks very simple:

```
web: bin/rails s
js: yarn run:js
css: yarn run:css
```

You can see the outputted colors below:

[image]

I was wondering how do I define and change these output colours on the left hand side in the console? I'd like to change the js from yellow as it looks a bit like a warning to me. The rest of the text on the right is the normal white and that's very helpful. Just want to change the left hand colors somewhere.

I've had a look in quite a few places and can't seem to find the settings or flag for this anywhere.

Comment: Just have idea how to colorize right column (using pipe in the Procfile). To change color in all log probably need change foreman sources

Comment: colors get [assigned](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/blob/v0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine/cli.rb#L91) based on the order of processes. put css second, it will be yellow instead. or use a different process manager, like [overmind](https://github.com/DarthSim/overmind#specifying-the-colors).